# This function will not display in a browser

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some basic javascript and I tried using a function, but the text will not display.

```js
var myheading = "This is my webpage!";
var text = "This JavaScript file makes use of Variables";
var linktag = "http://www.google.com/";
var begineffect = "<strong>";
var endeffect = "</strong>";
var linebreak = "<br />";

function numberone(myheading) {
  documment.write("<h2>" + myheading + "</h2>");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="variables_javascript.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would really appreciate the help!

Comment: Does anything actually call that function?

Comment: Also typo in `documment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling function also typo in `documment`

```js
var myheading = "This is my webpage!";
var text = "This JavaScript file makes use of Variables";
var linktag = "http://www.google.com/";
var begineffect = "<strong>";
var endeffect = "</strong>";
var linebreak = "<br />";
function numberone(myheading) {
  document.write("<h2>" +myheading+ "</h2>");
}

numberone(myheading)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Variables</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "variables_javascript.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I just started my course...
Does this need a ; after it?